# Oracle regular expression split string from last occurence

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I am still learning regexp in oracle I am stuck in middle, below is my sample code:

```
with t(val)
as
(
  --format: xyz_year_month_date
  select 'my_new_table_2015_06_31' from dual
  union all
  select 'my_new_table_temp_2016_06_31' from dual
 )
 select reverse(regexp_substr(reverse(val),'[^_]+',1,4)) col4,
 reverse(regexp_substr(reverse(val),'[^_]+',1,3)) col3,
 reverse(regexp_substr(reverse(val),'[^_]+',1,2)) col2,
 reverse(regexp_substr(reverse(val),'[^_]+',1,1)) col1
 from t;

Output:
COL4 COL3 COL2 COL1
table 2015 06 31
temp 2016 06 31

Expected output:
COL4 COL3 COL2 COL1
my_new_table 2015 06 31
my_new_table_temp 2016 06 31
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without the double reverse by extracting different capture groups (surrounded in round `()` brackets):

```
WITH t ( VAL ) AS (
  SELECT 'my_new_table_2015_06_31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'my_new_table_temp_2016_06_31' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( val, '^(.*)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS COL4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( val, '^(.*)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) AS COL3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( val, '^(.*)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 3 ) AS COL2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( val, '^(.*)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 4 ) AS COL1
FROM   t
```

You could even make the regular expression much simpler by just using:

```
'^(.+)_(.+)_(.+)_(.+)$'
```

The first `.+` is greedy so it will match as much as possible until there is only enough of the string left for the minimum matches on the 2nd - 4th capturing groups.

**However, you don't need regular expressions**:

```
WITH t ( VAL ) AS (
  SELECT 'my_new_table_2015_06_31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'my_new_table_temp_2016_06_31' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SUBSTR( val, 1,        pos1 - 1        ) AS col4,
       SUBSTR( val, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1 ) AS col3,
       SUBSTR( val, pos2 + 1, pos3 - pos2 - 1 ) AS col2,
       SUBSTR( val, pos3 + 1                  ) AS col1
FROM   (
  SELECT val,
         INSTR( val, '_', -1, 1 ) AS pos3,
         INSTR( val, '_', -1, 2 ) AS pos2,
         INSTR( val, '_', -1, 3 ) AS pos1
  FROM   t
);
```

Comment: What MT0 shows here is a technique you will need to learn anyway. The "stuff in parentheses" is called variously "capture group" or "back reference" or, in Oracle terminology, simply "subexpression." Available only in Oracle 11.1 and above, subexpressions can be used in regexp_substr: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm Read specifically the explanation of subexpression in the documentation (including examples).

Comment: Also, to allow for the possibility of null (what if the first part is empty, as in `_2013_04_10`?) - instead of .+ you can use .*  You knew that already.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your col4 regex to match the remainder of the string. The last parameter indicates the capture group from the regex match, the second but last parameter is only syntactically required (it holds match parameters).

The outer `substr` call on cols 1-3 gets rid of the underscore that is part of the matches.

```
with t(val)
as
(
  --format: xyz_year_month_date
  select 'my_new_table_2015_06_31' from dual
  union all
  select 'my_new_table_temp_2016_06_31' from dual
 )
 select reverse(regexp_substr(reverse(val),'([^_]+_){3}(.*)',1,1,'',2)) col4,
 substr(reverse(regexp_substr(reverse(val),'[^_]+_',1,3)), 2) col3,
 substr(reverse(regexp_substr(reverse(val),'[^_]+_',1,2)), 2) col2,
 substr(reverse(regexp_substr(reverse(val),'[^_]+_',1,1)), 2) col1
 from t;
```

Comment: Oracle 11g does support extracting capture groups using [`REGXP_SUBSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm) - They added a 6th parameter where you specify the capture group to return.

Comment: @MT0 You are right, I remembered the version oracle had introduced it wrongly.